# Charjs 2 with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chartjs

I am totally new to reactjs library. I found this library very interesting and want to implement in my chart-analyzing project(which is Java based spring project). Basically I want to implement it conventional way, do not want to install npm or any package manager. I have two files:

**File: index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.25.0/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.31.0/react-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-chartjs-2/2.1.0/react-chartjs-2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="chart.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="root"></div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

**File: chart.js**

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
      return <Line data={chartData} optionis={chartOptions} width="90%" height="70%" /> 
    }
});
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I think, it should work, but I get error:
***Uncaught ReferenceError: Line is not defined***

Note: I do NOT want to use npm manager. So, answers with **npm**, or using javascript **require** or **import** are not applicable to my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You HAVE TO import the chartJS library (or in ES5 its var Line = require('Line')).

Thats the reason the console said Line is not defined.

Comment: I have used var Line=require('Line'); I got : ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: can I see more of your code? If you got require is not defined thats probably means the environment set up is wrong somehow.

Comment: meaning the way you include react & react-dom is somehow bugged

Answer (score 0):

Try this react library 
 https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs . 
 You just have to run 
***npm install --save react-chartjs*** in you project .
Then simply import LineChart from eact-chartjs

```
 var LineChart = require("react-chartjs").Line;
    var MyComponent = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
      return <LineChart data={chartData} optionis={chartOptions} width="90%" height="70%" /> 
        }
    });
    ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Is it not possible without npm. I have included the react-chartjs in my html page and I want to run in browser, not in server.  Why you recommend react-chartjs instead of react-chartjs-2 ?